# Proving limit of multivariable function by definition.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to prove the following limit using $\ \varepsilon - \delta$ definition.

$\lim_{(x,y)->(a,\infty)} \frac{xy-1}{y+6}=a$

Now i have to prove that for every positive $\ \varepsilon $ there exists positive $\delta$ such that if distance between any point from the domain and point $\ (a, \infty)$ is less that $\ \delta$ then $ |f(x,y) - a| < \varepsilon$

Let $\ \varepsilon $ be positive number and in general case we look at expressiomn  $ |f(x,y) - a|$ and we try to express it usinf only $ \delta$ and constants where $|x+1|< \delta$ and $|y-c|< \delta$ where $c$ is a constant but in this case we have that y approaches infinity, how i am supposed to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since $y \to \infty$, we can assume that $y>0$. Now verify (with the triangle ineqaulity and the fact that $y+6 > y$) that

(*)  $|\frac{xy-1}{y+6}-a| \le |x-a|+\frac{1+6a}{y}$

If $ \varepsilon >0$ let $\delta=\varepsilon/2$. For $x,y$ with $|x-a|<\delta$ and $y>\frac{2}{\varepsilon}(1+6a)$ we get from (*):

$|\frac{xy-1}{y+6}-a| < \varepsilon.$

FRED

Comment: Why is $ \delta =\frac{ \varepsilon}{2}$ ?

Comment: To get $|\frac{xy-1}{y+6}-a| < \varepsilon.$

Comment: i don't understand why the fact that $ \delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ helps me to prove that $|\frac{xy-1}{y+6} - a| < \varepsilon$